# uiBreadcrumbs with AngularJS not populating breadcrumbs

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, breadcrumbs

I am using [angular breadcrumbs](https://github.com/ncuillery/angular-breadcrumb) for my project.

Have included the javascript as a bower install and save.

The HTML code is:

```html
    <div ng-include="'components/navbar/navbar.html'"></div>
    <div id="main" class="container-fluid">
    <div ui-view="sidebar"></div>
    <div class="col-md-10">
    <ui-breadcrumbs template-url="uiBreadcrumbs.tpl.html" displayname-property="data.displayName"></ui-breadcrumbs>
    <h3><div ui-view="heading"></div></h3>
    <div ui-view="content"></div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div ui-view="footer"></div>
```

Using ui-router, my state information reads like this:

```js
.state('config', {
        url:'/config',
        views: {
          '@':{
            templateUrl: 'app/main/configuration/configuration.html',
          },
          'sidebar@config':{
            templateUrl: 'app/main/configuration/configsidebar.html',
          },
          'heading@config':{
            template: 'Configurations'
          },
          'content@config':{
            template: '<p>some random content to be decided, mostly a dashboard.</p>'
          },
          'footer@config':{
            templateUrl: 'app/main/configuration/footer.html',
          }
        },
        controller: 'ConfigCtrl',
        data: {
          displayName: 'Config'
        }
      })
```

This according to the document is enough for showing the breadcrumb, but this isn't working for me. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the answer.

I was using a wrong path for the js file and thus wasn't able to load it.

Corrected the path, it works now.